# MiTek MySnap and IBM MobileFirst Platform

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm doing my first IBM Mobile First Platform project. I need to integrate a native SDK from MiTek called MySnap. I am following the directions to integrate the SDKs but I get this error.

I'm kind of new to Xcode so I don't know the errors really well yet.

> Ld
>   /Users/hannade/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativePagesInHybridAppNativePagesInHybridAppIphone-cxbsrcmfjjkjoxfcvhsngdyiicgs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NativePagesInHybridApp.app/NativePagesInHybridApp
>   normal i386
>       cd /Users/hannade/Developer/NativePagesInHybridApp/apps/NativePagesInHybridApp/iphone/native
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk
>   -L/Users/hannade/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativePagesInHybridAppNativePagesInHybridAppIphone-cxbsrcmfjjkjoxfcvhsngdyiicgs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -L/Users/hannade/Developer/NativePagesInHybridApp/apps/NativePagesInHybridApp/iphone/native
>   -L\"/Users/hannade/Developer/NativePagesInHybridApp/apps/NativePagesInHybridApp/iphone/native/WorklightSDK\"
>   -F/Users/hannade/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativePagesInHybridAppNativePagesInHybridAppIphone-cxbsrcmfjjkjoxfcvhsngdyiicgs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/hannade/Developer/NativePagesInHybridApp/apps/NativePagesInHybridApp/iphone/native
>   -F/Users/hannade/Developer/NativePagesInHybridApp/apps/NativePagesInHybridApp/iphone/native/Frameworks
>   -filelist /Users/hannade/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativePagesInHybridAppNativePagesInHybridAppIphone-cxbsrcmfjjkjoxfcvhsngdyiicgs/Build/Intermediates/NativePagesInHybridAppNativePagesInHybridAppIphone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NativePagesInHybridAppNativePagesInHybridAppIphone.build/Objects-normal/i386/NativePagesInHybridApp.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lstdc++ -lc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/hannade/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativePagesInHybridAppNativePagesInHybridAppIphone-cxbsrcmfjjkjoxfcvhsngdyiicgs/Build/Intermediates/NativePagesInHybridAppNativePagesInHybridAppIphone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NativePagesInHybridAppNativePagesInHybridAppIphone.build/NativePagesInHybridApp.app.xcent
>   -lstdc++.6 -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreTelephony -framework ImageIO -framework sqlcipher
>   /Users/hannade/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativePagesInHybridAppNativePagesInHybridAppIphone-cxbsrcmfjjkjoxfcvhsngdyiicgs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a
>   -lMiSnap -framework Security -lBarcodeScannerStub -framework CoreMedia -lz -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AVFoundation
>   -lCardIOStub -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreLocation -framework MediaPlayer -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration
>   -framework CoreMotion -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreData -lWorklightStaticLibProject -framework OpenGLES -Xlinker
>   -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/hannade/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativePagesInHybridAppNativePagesInHybridAppIphone-cxbsrcmfjjkjoxfcvhsngdyiicgs/Build/Intermediates/NativePagesInHybridAppNativePagesInHybridAppIphone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NativePagesInHybridAppNativePagesInHybridAppIphone.build/Objects-normal/i386/NativePagesInHybridApp_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/hannade/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativePagesInHybridAppNativePagesInHybridAppIphone-cxbsrcmfjjkjoxfcvhsngdyiicgs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NativePagesInHybridApp.app/NativePagesInHybridApp
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L"/Users/hannade/Developer/NativePagesInHybridApp/apps/NativePagesInHybridApp/iphone/native/WorklightSDK"'
>   ld: library not found for -lWorklightStaticLibProject clang: error:
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Open the Build Phases section of your project in Xcode and verify that in "Link Binary With Libraries", MFP's "libWorklightStaticLibProject.a" file is located at the *top* of the list of libraries.

Sometimes its lack of being at the top can cause build problems.

For example:
[image]

Comment: Tried moving it to the top same error happens, i also get warnings about it ignoring that file and the other .a files i imported for the mySnap sdk

Comment: Okay. I am not aware of support for this framework. If you can't get it to work and you're an IBM customer feel free to open a support ticket.